# how to fix Argument 'api_key' passed by position and keyword in constructor call

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am connecting my Django web app with the Airtable API and I have two errors. 
One in my editor (VSCode):

> [Argument 'api_key' passed by position and keyword in constructor call]

and the second in CMDER:

> [__init__() got multiple values for argument 'api_key']

Here is my code:

```
AT = Airtable(os.environ.get('AIRTABLE_MOVIESTABLE_BASE_ID'),
              'Movies',
              api_key=os.environ.get('AIRTABLE_API_KEY'))
```

Comment: Where does the `Airtable` class originates from?

Comment: Remove the last parameter (you've passed it in position 1 and the error message is complaining that you're passing it twice).

Comment: i fixed it, the problem in virtual env